C# WPF Change Text Event From TextBox
i have a problem. I made a new class called "LetterBox" this class inherits from TextBox everything is working for now. But here comes the problem: I need the Event or Function that "fills" the Text-Field.
For example: I press the 'T' Key and in the TextBox Text Field ist the letter T. But which event or function fills this field?
I wanna change the Text-Field from String to my own 'WordElement' object.
Here is my LetterBox class:
internal class LetterBox : TextBox
{
    public static List<WordElement> Letters { get; set; } = new();

    public LetterBox()
    {
        FontSize = 20;

        KeyDown += LetterBox_KeyDown;
    }
    
    // This event wont work as expected, because the Text gets added twice
    public void LetterBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve the Key that was pressed
        Key key = e.Key;
        char ckey = (char)key;

        WordElement we = new();
        
        // Set the Letter in the WordElement to manipulate it later
        we.SetLetter(ckey);
        
        Letters.Add(we);

        // Delete the Text to "refresh" it
        Text = "";

        // Put every Letter from the list back in the Text
        foreach (WordElement wordElement in Letters)
        {
            Text += wordElement.Letter;
        }
    }
}

Here is my WordElement class:
internal class WordElement
{
    public char Letter { get; private set; }
    public Color Color { get; private set; } = Colors.Black;
    public float Size { get; private set; } = 12;
    public bool Bold { get; private set; } = false;
    public bool Italic { get; private set; } = false;
    public bool Underlined { get; private set; } = false;

    public void SetLetter(char letter)
    {
        Letter = letter;
    }

    public void SetColor(Color color)
    {
        Color = color;
    }

    public void SetSize(float size)
    {
        Size = size;
    }

    public void SetBold(bool bold)
    {
        Bold = bold;
    }

    public void SetItalic(bool italic)
    {
        Italic = italic;
    }

    public void SetUnderlined(bool underlined)
    {
        Underlined = underlined;
    }
}

Hopefully you understand my problem and can help me :)
P.S.: my english is not the best :P

May I ask what exactly you are trying to achieve? Clearing all text on every input is not very efficient and will very likely cause issues as it will always raise the TextChanged event. What is the idea? Why are you clearing all input only to add it back? The concat enation in your loop is also inefficient in terms of speed and memory.

its for a bigger project that i am working on, this code is in another solution to test an idea i had for an own textbox kind of thing. i want a textbox where i can color some parts of the text like what i select can be change in color or font etc. but i dont want to use the richtextbox because i dont want the rtf format. i want it like it is in the word element class, so i can do something like: "Letter[3].Color" to get the color of this letter

Ah, I see. but TextBox is the wrong control to highlight ext isn't it? It does not support formatted text. You should take a look into FormattedText. This allows you to render text manually. You can format character by character. You can draw the FormattedText using DrawingContext.DrawText.  The TextBox won't get you anywhere for sure. I wouldn't waste any more time on it. It's specialized for text input. Plain-text input.

You can also use a TextBlock and compose it using formatted Run elements like you would do in a FlowDocument. But TextBlock is not meant to display large texts. For larger texts you may want to look into the FormattedText. You can control the caret using Win32 API.

I know that i cant display formatted text with the standard TextBox but i used it in this test solution to test my classes, the next step would be to have something like a textbox that can show formatted text and the user can edit the text (it needs to be "a textbox"). my bigger project is a tool for people who wants to wirte storys or books and the textbox or textfield is the most important thing, but to make things easier for me for the future things i have in mind, i want it to work with the WordElement class.

also i made the LetterBox which i thought i can make my own textbox with this formatted text because richtextbox inherits from textbox class too, right? so i am trying to use the class to made my own textbox.

RichTextBox does not inherit from TextBox. It inherits TextBoxBase. That's a huge difference as all the text container handling is missing. And RichTextBox does not use the default text container as it operates on a FlowDocument. Don't think that this is going to be an easy task. You have to implement all text rendering and interaction like caret positioning and keyboard commands, text selection, from scratch. I'm not saying that this is beyond your skills (just saying this to prevent a misinterpretation of my words).

I'm just warning you that it is not as simple as subclassing "TextBox" (the way you put it) and then simply replace the text characters. Before you start to test your WordElement class I would test how to render and control text in a custom text container. If you succeed then continue to refine. You are starting at the wrong end that likely leads to a lot of wasted hours because you finally decide to pick a 3rd party library because you are stuck or overwhelmed by the effort it takes.

Set e.Handled = true; to suppress the standard handling of the input in LetterBox_KeyDown.
But if you derive from another control, you would override OnKeyDown instead of subscribing to the event and then simply not call base.OnKeyDown(); to suppress the standard handling of the input.
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Your code
}


Thank you for your answer, i simply forgot that "e.Handled = true" surpresses the standard handling, but its working now :)
